# Animation Hover Effect working in Firefox and Chrome but only once in Safari

Tags: css, animation

I have animation setup for a dropdown hover effect and it works each time I hover over it in Firefox and Chrome but it only works on the first hover in Safari.

This is my code, do I need to add anything for it to work everytime I hover in Safari?

```
#nav ul li:hover ul  {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 25px rgba(38, 51, 54, .1);
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
    background: #fff;
    animation-duration: .8s;
    animation-name: updown; 
}
@keyframes updown {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(30%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

Comment: On the face of it there doesn't seem to be any obvious reason this would not work in Safari. Could you create a runnable snippet and make sure it shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here is the url of the site - https://cadence.pt-devsites.com.  Does it do each time you hover over it in Safari or just once?

Comment: Code direct into your question please, see the link above about how to create a minimal reproducibel example. The reason for requiring this is so that once your site is 'cured' the problem won't be there for future readers so your question and any answers won't be useful to them.

Comment: And yes, it works repeatedly on Safari (IOS 16.1) when I test it on Solutions tab on your site so you really do need to create a snippet which shows the problem, and tell us what OS and what Safari version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a problem with other part of your code. This snippet works in safari too.

```css
#nav ul{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  position:relative
}
#nav ul li ul{
  position:absolute;
  display: none;
  left:0;
  top: 35px;
}
#nav ul li ul li{
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap
}
#nav ul li:hover ul  {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 25px rgba(38, 51, 54, .1);
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
    background: #fff;
    animation-duration: .8s;
    animation-name: updown; 
}

@keyframes updown {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(30%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Page A</li>
    <li>Categories
      <ul>
        <li>Sub Menu A</li>
        <li>Sub Menu B</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I should have included the url of the site - https://cadence.pt-devsites.com.  Does it do each time you hover over it in Safari or just once?